# Назначение символа * при создании объекта в котлине

Tags: java, kotlin

Здравствуйте. Перевел код с  java на kotlin  со помощью автоматического конвертера. Появилась конструкция, которую я не могу понять. Что означает звездочка при создании объекта (**return Sort(*orders)**) ? Мне нужно хотя бы название этой конструкции для дальнейшего гугления.

```
class Sort (vararg orders: SortOrder) {

var orders: List<SortOrder> = ArrayList()

companion object {
    fun sort(vararg orders: SortOrder): Sort {
        return Sort(*orders)
    }
}

init {
    this.orders = Arrays.asList(*orders)
}

override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
    if (this === other) return true
    if (other == null || javaClass != other.javaClass) return false
    val sort = other as Sort?

    return orders == sort!!.orders
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html#operators-and-special-symbols)

> +, -, *, /, % - mathematical operators
>
> `*` is also used to pass an array to a `vararg` parameter (*также используется для передачи массива параметру `vararg`*)

[Также](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs)

> When we call a `vararg`-function, we can pass arguments one-by-one, e.g.
>   asList(1, 2, 3), or, if we already have an array and want to pass its
>   contents to the function, we use the spread operator (prefix the array
>   with *):
>
> ```
> val a = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
> val list = asList(-1, 0, *a, 4)
> ```

Перевод

*Когда мы вызываем vararg-функцию, мы можем передавать аргументы один за другим, например, `asList (1, 2, 3)`, или, если у нас уже есть массив и мы хотим передать его содержимое функции, мы используем оператор распространения (spread) (префикс массива с `*`):*